# Trigger on opportunity error - Field is not writeable: OpportunityPartner.Role

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm creating a trigger to update a field depending on a partner role, but receiving the following error. Any help would be much appreciated!

Error: Compile Error: Field is not writeable: OpportunityPartner.Role at line 32 column 5 -  if (r.role = 'End-User') opps.EndUser_Partner__c = r.AccountToId;

```
trigger EndUserPartner on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

Set<Id> OppIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {OppIds.add(o.id);}

Map<Id, List<OpportunityPartner>> Opp_partner = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityPartner>>();

for (OpportunityPartner opppart : [select id, AccountToId, Opportunityid, role, isprimary, createddate from OpportunityPartner where opportunityid in :OppIds and role = 'End-User']) {

List<OpportunityPartner> tmp_opppart = new List<OpportunityPartner>();
tmp_opppart = Opp_partner.get(opppart.opportunityid);
if (tmp_opppart == null) {
Opp_partner.put(opppart.opportunityid, new List<OpportunityPartner>{opppart});
} else {

tmp_opppart.add(opppart);
Opp_partner.put(opppart.opportunityid, tmp_opppart);
}
} 
system.debug('Final Opp_partner map: '+Opp_partner);


for (Opportunity opps : Trigger.new) {
List<OpportunityPartner> this_opppart = new List<OpportunityPartner>();
this_opppart = Opp_partner.get(opps.id);
system.debug('this Opps ('+opps.id+') list of oppparts: '+this_opppart);

if (this_opppart == null) opps.EndUser_Partner__c = null;
else {

for (OpportunityPartner r : this_opppart) {
if (r.role = 'End-User') opps.EndUser_Partner__c = r.AccountToId;
} 
} 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You used a single = (assignment operator) when you meant to use == (the equality operator). It's legal to assign as part of a conditional branch, but it's usually unintentional.